# which printable paper data storage format has the best information capacity?

Tags: encoding, fonts, character-encoding, ocr

I need to store data on a sheet of paper that is meant to be digitally processed. Once delivered, the sheet will be photographed with a smartphone camera.

What's the most effective barcode format, that can store the largest number of 8-bits characters?

How many bytes per page can be stored?

Answer (score 2):

[High Capacity Color Barcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Capacity_Color_Barcode) (HCCB), [Data Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix) and [QRcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QRcode) have a high capacity and can be packed on a single A4 page. The information capacity depends on the printing and scanning resolution, and can reach 50-70kb per page at 600 DPI ([see recent experiments](https://www.monperrus.net/martin/store-data-paper)).

Other less standard formats include the [paperback format](http://ollydbg.de/Paperbak/) ([linux version](https://git.teknik.io/scuti/paperback-cli)), the [optar format](http://ronja.twibright.com/optar/), the  [colorsafe format](https://github.com/colorsafe/colorsafe/).

See also:

- [Paper data storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_data_storage)
- [Popular 2D Bar Codes](http://www.adams1.com/stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of now highest HCCB I've found that works is JAB code

More on this [here](https://hvitis.dev/jab-code-and-everything-you-need-to-know-about-color-bar-code)